# Importing video with very low frame rate into kdenlive

Tags: kdenlive

I'm trying to import a video that has an effective frame rate of about 3.3 fps from a stream that I captured with the ffmpeg command line tool.

The video profile seems to be reporting that the frame rate is 25 fps; so it plays at high speed.

What should I do to get the video to play at the correct speed?

Answer (score 0):

I discovered that when one puts the video on the timeline, and right clicks on the clip and selects "change speed", one can enter the rate that the clip should play (as a percentage).

When I changed the percentage, the rendered video played at the correct speed.